# Location of CouchDB in Hyperledger offline

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have installed all the required components to run hyperledger composer locally on my PC. I can test run my code on Angular and everything works fine. I wanted to know where my database is actually stored so I tried the solution given on this link:
[Where does hyperledger fabric store the database for the blockchain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656547/where-does-hyperledger-fabric-store-the-database-for-the-blockchain)
But in my var directory there is no subfolder as hyperledger, I want to locate my database on the PC, please help!

Comment: Just to be sure, you have looked in the peer container directories and not your local PC directories, right?

Answer (score 0):

It is running as a container.
Couchdb provided an offline user interface called Fauxton.
You can access it through the following link.
https://localhost:5984/_utils
Change IP and port number if you're using a different one.